# XAML "The member `isChecked` is not recognized or accessable" error for a RadioButton style trigger

Tags: c#, xaml

I have two `RadioButton`s that I'd like to change the text on based on their `IsChecked` state, but Visual Studio is telling me `IsChecked` and `Content` aren't recognized/accessable. The below code is the same for both buttons.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="{Binding CommunicatingGroupName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsCommunicating}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsActive}" FontSize="11" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" Content="ACTIVE" >
    <RadioButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{StaticResource ButtonBlue}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked"  Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="ACTIVE" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="STANDBY" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="ACTIVE" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Style>
</RadioButton>
```

I have `ToggleButtons` elsewhere in the file that work with the same `<Style.Triggers>` elements, and as far as I know should work the same way for these `RadioButton`s. Am I missing something specific to RadioButtons? I've rebuilt, restarted VS, etc. and the errors persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
<Style TargetType="{StaticResource ButtonBlue}">
```

You set target type to something that looks like style. Probably you tried to write something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonBlue}">
```

Comment: Yep i mistyped it. That second line is even what the other togglebuttons look like above in the file... dangit